# WP Editor: Keep Bold, Underline, etc. but ignore color

Tags: tinymce, formatting

Since upgrading to WP 3.9, my clients have been complaining that the new editor keeps *too much* formatting.

They'd like it so when you paste it keeps the formatting of bold, underline, paragraph breaks, etc. but ignores any color formatting. They tell me the old tinymce editor did this.

Is there a way to do this?  No look searching around the web and here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The TinyMCE documentation suggests you can configure exactly which tags are valid using the [paste_word_valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3apaste_word_valid_elements) init option. I haven't tested this, but you should be able to customize the list to fit their needs exactly.